# Solving generalized eigenvalue system with a semidefinite positive B in python

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to use Normalized Cut algorithm *(Shi and Malik, 2000)* to cut a matrix into two matrices. In this regard, I need to find the second smallest eigenvector in a generalized eigenvalue system **(Ax = lambda.B.x)**. In my input, B is a semidefinite positive matrix. However, `scipy.linalg.eigh` requires B to be definite positive and raises an error when I use it. I need to know if I can have a solution with this input, and how can I find it.

I tried

```
eigvals, eigvecs = eigh(A, B, eigvals_only=False, subset_by_index=[0, 1])
```

But I got:

```
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: The leading minor of order 2 of B is not positive definite. The factorization of B could not be completed and no eigenvalues or eigenvectors were computed.
```

Answer (score 0):

If `B` is semidefinite, it means it has at least one eigenvector associated with an eigenvalue `0`, you still could have solutions if the nullspace of B is also a null space of A, i.e. if `B @ x = 0`, `A @ x = 0`, but in that case the generalized eigenvalue associated with `x` is undetermined.